# Sql group by date issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables as below,

```
------------------    --------------------
| leads          |    | leads_tracking    |
------------------    --------------------
| id             |    | tracking_id       |
| lead_id        |    | lead_id           |
| tix            |    | field_name        |
| order_number   |    | date              |
------------------    ---------------------
```

I need to get the sum of **tix** and group them by **date** (and order number is not empty)

I tried write sql:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(tracking_leads.date, "%m.%d.%Y") as trackDate, SUM(l.tix) as sumValue 
FROM leads as l 
INNER JOIN tracking_leads ON l.lead_id=tracking_leads.lead_id 
WHERE tracking_leads.field_name='tix' 
  AND l.is_active = 1 
  AND l.is_archive = 0 
  AND l.dont_show_in_list=0 
  AND order_number <> '' 
  and transaktions_nr IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(tracking_leads.date, "%m.%d.%Y")
```

I don't have all groups that I need.

What's wrong with my code please?

Comment: "I dont have all groups that i need. "  What is this supposed to mean?  How do we know what *you* need?  You don't even have anything that identifies a "group" in your data.  Your `WHERE` conditions are also incompatible, so all rows will be filtered out.  Sample data and desired results and an explanation of the logic would help.

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the same columns as you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: group is 'date' in the second table

Comment: @jarlh, sorry cant understand your comment. There are errors in my sql?

Comment: Not at all. Your current query looks fine, you're following my advice. What I can't understand is what you mean with "I don't have all groups that i need". Add some sample table data and the expected result to make things clearer. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking for. Are you saying that you want to SUM(l.tix) even if there are no tracking_leads and you wish to group by order_number ?

Comment: Is the issue that you're losing the leads that have no tracking_leads thus far? are you expecting to see some dates in the results but just not getting them?  Do such dates even exist in teh tracking_leads?  Sample data expected results would help clarify what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Add **order_number** to your query and check the result. You might get some idea. Try this:

```
SELECT order_number,DATE_FORMAT(tracking_leads.date, "%m.%d.%Y") as trackDate, SUM(l.tix) as 
sumValue 

FROM leads as l 
INNER JOIN tracking_leads ON l.lead_id=tracking_leads.lead_id 

WHERE tracking_leads.field_name='tix' 
  AND l.is_active = 1 
  AND l.is_archive = 0 
  AND l.dont_show_in_list=0 
  AND order_number <> '' 
  and transaktions_nr IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY order_number,tracking_leads.date
```